# A specific feature is available at runtime

Tags: javascript

I and others caution against trying to detect which browser is running one’s JavaScript .What can a developer do instead to see whether a specific feature is available at runtime?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)? Also this question is *way* too broad. Which feature are you specifically interested in, and can you fall back to something else?

Comment: Yes, use feature-detection. If you have settled on a *particular feature* you want to detect and can't find a way to do it, please ask a new question about that specific feature.